# Send bulk message using WhatsApp API using PHP

Tags: php, whatsapp

I have implemented WhatsApp message system via web using [this](https://github.com/mgp25/WhatsAPI-Official) API now i can send `text` `image` and `video` message to some WhatsApp contacts without using a phone. However can I use this api for bulk messaging through WhatsApp? that means can i use it for production purpose?

I just read about from this [blog post](http://www.sumitgupta.net/whatsapp-messaging-from-web/comment-page-1/#comment-2851) but cant understand the whole thing.

Comment: Check TOS of WhatsApp. You probably can't do this.

Comment: So its not possible via this api

Comment: Don't do so please. It's too annoying.

Comment: ok if it is not possible then whats use that api

Comment: Whatsapp does not provide such API, what you're doing violates their ToS